# UI5 Router destroying cached views

Tags: sapui5

I have a Master Details Page App where we configured the Router for the same to navigate between pages.

App.view.xml

```
<SplitApp id="rootControl" detailNavigate="onDetailNavigation">
</SplitApp>
```

manifest.json

```
"routing": {
                "config": {
                    "routerClass": "sap.m.routing.Router",
                    "viewPath": "master",
                    "controlId": "rootControl",
                    "viewType": "XML",
                    "async":"true"
                },
                "routes": [
                    {
                        ....
                    },
                    ...
                "targets": {}
                   ...
```

App is simple Employee CRUD app, i have configured the router with 2 routes 1 for Create/Edit and another one for Dispaly

I need to destroy the view if i navigate from one view to another view, like on start of the page show the Master Page with all the employees and detail page show display view of the employee1.

i have Edit button on the Display view, on press i navigate details page from Display view to Edit View, on this point i need to destroy the Display view from the router, which is cached.

**How to achive this? or do i need to take different approch to solve the cacheing? or I should not think of Memory**

tried calling destroy onDetailNavigate of SplitApp

```
onDetailNavigation : function(oEvent){
            console.log("Split app onDetailNavigation");
            oEvent.getParameter('from').destroy();
        }
```

Which gives Error next time go back to same view again

```
Error: The object with ID __xmlview4 was destroyed and cannot be used anymore.
```

Comment: What happens if you [remove](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.SplitContainer/methods/removeDetailPage) the `from` view first and then destroy it? Would you get the same error if you navigate back to the same view next time?

Comment: Let me try once

Comment: made the below change `var splitApp = this.getView().byId('rootControl');
   splitApp.removeDetailPage(oEvent.getParameter('from'));
   oEvent.getParameter('from').destroy();` still same error

Comment: but if i not destroy the router has the instance of view but removed from DOM

Comment: i made some changes to remove from router as below, is this fine?`var router = this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter();
   for(var view in router._oViews._oViews){
    if( router._oViews._oViews[view].sId === oEvent.getParameter('fromId') )
    {
     delete router._oViews._oViews[view];
    }
   }`

Comment: Why do you need to destroy views?

Comment: @matbtt to save memory, thing when i do edit an employee need to load the Input control for employee name, but when in display mode i need to show in Text control for name.

Comment: Premature optimization is the root of all evil... I don't see any benefit in saving the memory allocated by some input or text controls. Instead you add overhead in creating views again and again in each navigation.

Comment: how about creating 2 fragments one for Display(text control) another one for Edit(Input control) and handling in controller based on edit or view? is that code follow proper design? means proper MVC because controller have both view part and edit part also

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since my Question is about the destroying the view from Router which are cached, i have followed the @boghyon comment and made some changes in my code as below which removes the pages after navigation of detail page as below

```
var splitApp = this.getView().byId('rootControl'); 
splitApp.removeDetailPage(oEvent.getParameter('from'));
```

and to remove the cached view from router i have wrote some logic

```
var router = this.getOwnerComponent().getRouter(); 
for(var view in router._oViews._oViews){
if( router._oViews._oViews[view].sId === oEvent.getParameter('fromId'){ 
 delete router._oViews._oViews[view]; 
 } 
}
```

Which destroy the view.

By doing this which loads the views multiple times and this is not proper ways for my requirement we have follow the @matbtt answer.

Thank you both for the valueable input.

Answer (score 1):

According to the comments you destroy views to save the memory allocated by your two views. I do not think this brings any real benefit. There are three possible solutions:

- Stick with the current solution.
- Use a single view and switch between a display and a edit fragment. An example can be found [here](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.ui.layout.sample.SimpleForm354/preview).
- Use a single view with a form with input fields. Bind the editable attribute against a model (e.g. view model) property reflecting edit or display state of the whole form or per property.

`<Input value="{applicationModel>/propertyName}" editable="{viewModel>/editable}"/>`

I'm using a version of the third solution. My application model (extending JSONModel) holds the application data plus a state controlling the property. The controller just calls setEditable on the application model which computes the state. Using this approach I avoid to spread the logic accross to many parts of the application.

`<Input value="{applicationModel>/propertyName}" editable="{applicationModel>/Attributes/propertyName/editable}"/>`

Comment: if we are loading suggestion items to Input control which is not required by the display view, and lot of code we have to write in controller to handle the enable and disable logic, so my idea is multiple views have clear sepration of the code and control and controller method

Comment: Suggestion items should be loaded on demand. Thus it is no argument against a combine display/edit view, you simply do not load suggestions in display mode. If you worry about too much code in the controller move it to the model.

Comment: i will take this thanks but to close this question i will go with @boghyon comment and answer for that. thanks for your valueable input